# Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am struggling to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} dx$$
 I tried a lot to factorize the expression but I didn't reach the solution.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Is the denominator supposed to be divided by two or is the whole term supposed to be to the $3/2$ power? It appears @azarel fixed it, but I just want to clarify.

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$
put $x=\sin(t)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

Set $x=\sin(t)$, then everything will turn out very well.

This often helps when you have some expresion like $1-x^2$ in your integral.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2}}=[x=\sin t]=\int\frac{\cos t dt}{\cos^3 t}=\int\frac{dt}{\cos^2 t}=\tan t$$

Comment: $= \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$, without which the answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle (1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} =x^3(\frac{1}{x^2}-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

From it you can substitute:

$\displaystyle [\frac{1}{x^2}-1] =z$

By differentiating both sides
we will get $\displaystyle \frac{-2}{x^3}dx=dz$.

In this way we can also solve the integral.

Comment: Are you sure about the equality you stated?..

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Friend you can check my answer.

Comment: I am referring to the first equality. Plug in $x=2$, for example...  It doesn't work...

Comment: I think now you are okk with the solution.@ Ludolila.